# Visual Studio 2010 Setup Project doesn't fully install application for all users

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project

I have an application and Visual Studio 2010 Setup Project and Windows XP. During installation, my setup project is making some registry entries in HKLM registry. During startup, my application is making some entries in HKCU registry. Installer action is added to Install, Commit, Uninstall and Rollback folders.

Now to the point. I have two users: admin and restricted user (let's say Johnny).
From admin account, I run installer, I choose "For all users" option and installation is completed successfully. Double click on desktop shortcut to my app and it starts normally.
Then, I open regedit and grant access in full read/write/modify mode to HKLM registry to Johnny. The same thing with installation folder. After all that, I simply delete the installer msi file.

I log into the Johnny account and double click desktop shortcut and installer runs! And it ends with error ofcourse, because it cannot find installer file which I previously deleted. Strange thing to me is, that if I double click on an application's exe file in Program Files, my app starts normally (without that installer thing). 
I've also noticed, that InstallState file is being left after installation process, but deleting it has no effect.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a situation, that after successful installation from admin account Johnny may run the app without any installer actions made by system before first run.

Can You please point me into the right direction?
Thanks in advance,
Piotrek

Comment: Does really noone knows the answer?

Comment: I'm also interested in a solution for this seemingly simple and common problem. I did run across this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796328/install-for-all-users-and-data-access, but I would like to see an answer to this simpler question.

Comment: Finally, after days of looking for an answer, I created new installer project and everything worked. o_O. Unfortunately, I don't know what made the difference.